# Source of randomness for .NET 7's System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes() method on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, random

I am trying to determine whether or not the GetBytes(Int32) method uses /dev/urandom when running in Linux (Ubuntu).  From what I can tell here:

Using [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net) I believe I have traced the code to here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/522c281d5e2ccbfa9a114018a7309965571ab4b6/src/libraries/Common/src/Interop/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native/Interop.RAND.cs

Which has the following:

```
        internal static unsafe bool GetRandomBytes(byte* pbBuffer, int count)
        {
            Debug.Assert(count >= 0);

            return CryptoNative_GetRandomBytes(pbBuffer, count) != 0;
        }

        [LibraryImport(Libraries.CryptoNative)]
        private static unsafe partial int CryptoNative_GetRandomBytes(byte* buf, int num);
```

Which makes me lean towards the answer being "Yes" on Linux the .NET Crypto RNG GetBytes() method is probably using /dev/urandom under the hood.

Is there any way I can know conclusively though?

I haven't really tried anything yet.  I suppose I could set up a simple test to call GetBytes() with a very large number and then see if /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail drops ... but is that even a good test?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a [Japanese Powershell blog](https://blog.shibata.tech/entry/2017/12/13/000500), tracking one step deeper gets us to the internal implementation of `CryptoNative_GetRandomBytes` in [`openssl.c`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v3.1.32/src/Native/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native/openssl.c) which (other than now being written directly in C rather than as C++ calling C) appears to be unchanged from the time that blog post was written:

```c
/*
Function:
GetRandomBytes

Puts num cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes into buf.

Return values:
Returns a bool to managed code.
1 for success
0 for failure
*/
int32_t CryptoNative_GetRandomBytes(uint8_t* buf, int32_t num)
{
    int ret = RAND_bytes(buf, num);

    return ret == 1;
}
```

So, what does this call to OpenSSL's `RAND_bytes` do? Well, the [official documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RAND_bytes.html) states the following:

> On all major platforms supported by OpenSSL (including the Unix-like platforms and Windows), OpenSSL is configured to automatically seed the CSPRNG on first use using the operating systems's random generator.

Now, I am largely unfamiliar with the inner workings of both OpenSSL and Operating Systems generally, so it was unclear to me precisely what is meant by this, especially as I am aware that there is both a `/dev/random` and a `/dev/urandom`. Luckily, the [OpenSSL FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.inc) explains this:

> All OpenSSL versions try to use /dev/urandom by default; starting with version 0.9.7, OpenSSL also tries /dev/random if /dev/urandom is not available.

So yes, OpenSSL will try to seed its own PRNG from `/dev/urandom` initially, however it appears the .NET `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes` method itself is actually only making calls to that PRNG, rather than utilising `/dev/urandom` directly.

Finally, see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/47882/299325) on the Information Security sister site for  a more thorough explanation the workings of `RAND_bytes` than I could hope to give, and also a possible method for tracking whether OpenSSL has utilised `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` specifically.